# How do I use a date in an Expect script?

Tags: expect

I need to have access to the current date (or time) within the Expect script so that I can add it to the directories that are created within the Expect script, e.g. something similar to these needs to get done:

```
mkdir file<date>
```

I can get the date via the shell as:

```sh
date | tr " " "-" | cut -f 2,4 -d "-"
```

However, I cannot get access to it in Expect, e.g. I cannot do something like:

```sh
set var = `date | tr " " "-" | cut -f 2,4 -d "-"`
```

I put this in a shell script, echo it and get the output in `$expect_out(buffer)` as detailed [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17378). However, the buffer also gets the prompt which needs to be removed as mentioned *Also, note that `$expect_out(buffer)` doesn't really hold what people want; it typically needs to be filtered down at least to eliminate the prompt.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Expect, you would use the builtin [`clock`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/clock.htm) command:

```
set now [clock seconds]
set date [clock format $now -format {%b-%d}]
set file file.$date
```

Or in one go:

```
set file file.[clock format [clock seconds] -format {%b-%d}]
```

I would strongly encourage you to use a date format that sorts sensibly

```
set file file.[clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y-%m-%d}]
```

Comment: Excellent response. Thanks.

Comment: @doon In Expect you can use `timestamp` built-in command like `set file file.[timestamp -format {%Y-%m-%d}]`.

Answer (score 2):

Cut from an Expect script:

```
# Set DATE variable in expect script
set DATE [exec date +%F]
send "This is a test with Expect on $DATE - try 4\r"
send ".\r"
```